# How to display list items store in different Web Application without REST?

Tags: web-part, rest, data-view-web-part, visual-web-part, web

I have an one intranet site, and one public site. These have different web application.
I want to display Tasks list and also insert items in intranet site into public site.

I try to add XsltListViewWebPart into page of public site, but this just worked for displaying list store the same Site Colletion.
The best way I know is used REST service and get data from Tasks list and display it into public site. 
But the cons of this way is not having the button New Item of the task, and we need to fill Task Items into Grid view to display it.

I want this Tasks List can work good in XsltListViewWebPart but I can't. 
So, please help if you have any ideas or the best solution about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The CSWP can return any content from the search index. Use it on your SharePoint 2013 sites when you are connecting to a search service and want to return indexed search results in your pages.

The CSWP returns content that is as fresh as the latest crawl of your content, so if you crawl often, the content that the CSWP returns is more up-to-date than if you crawl infrequently. If you need to display instant content or the refreshed version of content, use the Content Query Web Part (CQWP) instead.

Search crawls only the major versions of content, never the minor versions. If you want to display the minor versions of your content, do that by using a CQWP.

Some site collection administrators mark sites to not be indexed. Content marked in this way is not available in a CSWP. If you want to return results from a site that is marked to not index, use the CQWP instead.

Ref Link : http://nikpatel.net/2014/02/28/content-query-web-part-vs-content-by-search-web-part/